# Can't disable SSHD banner

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, sshd

So, I have a WD MyBookLive NAS, which runs an ugly PPC build of Debian Squeeze. It has SSH access enabled, and when I log in, I get a long banner message (closer to an epic saga in length) about "Don't allow anyone access who you don't trust, blah, blah, blah." Understandably, I would like to disable it.

So, I go poke at `\etc\ssh\sshd_config` file, to see where it's enabled, and I find this:

```
#Banner /etc/issue.net
```

and

```
PrintMotd no
```

It's not even enabled. But just to make sure I wasn't losing it, I checked `issue` and `issue.net`, and each had a single line declaring the kernel/distro, not the novella that I see on login.

What am I missing? I can provide any further information if/as you need it.

Comment: Never realized till now, that when we talk about a "SSHD" in the context of a NAS, we could be talking about SSH Daemon or Solid State Hybrid Drive. :(

Comment: Hahaa never thought of that. SSH Daemon, in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forgot how many levels of auth can throw MOTDs. It was PAM's fault. pam_motd, to be exact, specified in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`